# Using miniconda to install anaconda and getting [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am new to Python/Anaconda and trying to do some self-learning on my company owned laptop (Windows). Downloading Anaconda from the site kept failing, so I downloaded miniconda and ran `conda install anaconda`. It displayed all of the packages that would be downloaded, installed, updated. I proceeded and most of the packages got to 100% but then I got [Errno 13] which said permission was denied for libtiff package.

Doing some research, I tried running the conda prompt in Admin mode, Didn't help. Tried doing a clean all command and retried the `conda install anaconda` command multiple times as I thought it may finish where it left off, but no luck, I keep getting some version of permission denied error for the libtiff package. I tried doing `conda install anaconda-navigator` but that didn't work either. Maybe there is an easy workaround to avoid miniconda altogether? I have some results from my last run today below.

```
(base) C:\Users\jaugustin>conda install anaconda
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\jaugustin\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - anaconda


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    jpeg-9b                    |       hb83a4c4_2         313 KB
    xz-5.2.4                   |       h2fa13f4_4         812 KB
    zlib-1.2.11                |       h62dcd97_3         128 KB
    zstd-1.3.7                 |       h508b16e_0         536 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         1.7 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  alabaster          pkgs/main/win-64::alabaster-0.7.12-py37_0
  anaconda           pkgs/main/win-64::anaconda-2019.03-py37_0
  anaconda-client    pkgs/main/win-64::anaconda-client-1.7.2-py37_0
  anaconda-project   pkgs/main/win-64::anaconda-project-0.8.2-py37_0
```

Many more NEW packages listed as well...

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

  cffi                                1.11.5-py37h74b6da3_1 --> 1.12.2-py37h7a1dbc1_1
  cryptography                         2.4.2-py37h7a1dbc1_0 --> 2.6.1-py37h7a1dbc1_0
  menuinst                            1.4.14-py37hfa6e2cd_0 --> 1.4.16-py37he774522_0
  pip                                           18.1-py37_0 --> 19.0.3-py37_0
  pyopenssl                                   18.0.0-py37_0 --> 19.0.0-py37_0
  python                                   3.7.1-h8c8aaf0_6 --> 3.7.3-h8c8aaf0_0
  setuptools                                  40.6.3-py37_0 --> 40.8.0-py37_0
  sqlite                                  3.26.0-he774522_0 --> 3.27.2-he774522_0
  wheel                                       0.32.3-py37_0 --> 0.33.1-py37_0
  win_inet_pton                                1.0.1-py37_1 --> 1.1.0-py37_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  pyparsing          pkgs/main/noarch::pyparsing-2.4.0-py_0 --> pkgs/main/win-64::pyparsing-2.3.1-py37_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
xz-5.2.4             | 812 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
zlib-1.2.11          | 128 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
zstd-1.3.7           | 536 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
jpeg-9b              | 313 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

CondaVerificationError: The package for libtiff located at C:\Users\jaugustin\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\pkgs\libtiff-4.0.10-hb898794_2
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Library/bin/libtiff.dll'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.
```

Many more similar errors are listed all with the libtiff package for various files.

Comment: Can you try `conda clean --all` then installing again?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @darthbith. Ran it and then it downloaded and extracted a bunch of packages, then threw the below error:
`[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\jaugustin\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\pkgs\\libtiff-4.0.10-hb898794_2\\Library\\bin\\tiff2pdf.exe'`

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening, but it sounds like a problem with the package.

Comment: @darthbith any thoughts on why my anaconda download gets to 99% and then says it cannot be downloaded?

Comment: No, sorry I don't

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, some of the security patches has blacklisted an exe file tiff2pdf.exe.
If you try to create a text file abc.txt at that folder C:\Users\jaugustin\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\pkgs\libtiff-4.0.10-hb898794_2\Library\bin\ and rename it as tiff2pdf.exe it would ask Admin privilage and still it may block you. 
Your System admin may be able to help you resolve.